# Any tutorial on Qt SOAP

Tags: qt, soap

Qt library provides a classes to work with SOAP in [qt components](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/solutions/4/qtsoap/qtsoap-overview.html). Unfortunately, it's not a part of 'core' Qt and is not well documented. Is it any tutorials / guides/ examples awailable i can use as starting point to learn QtSoap? I want to create a very simple SOAP client for JIRA.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://doc.qt.nokia.com/solutions/4/qtsoap/google-example.html how about this i think it's a good example

also the documentation for every class is decent eg : http://doc.qt.nokia.com/solutions/4/qtsoap/qtsoapmessage.html#details

Comment: Yes, the documentation is decent, but it is thry short, for example 'SetAction' and 'setMethod' are documented like 'sets SOAP action' and 'sets SOAP method' :). And i'm kinda amused what value to supply for JIRA soap service. It's kind of different than in google example.

Comment: Well you should also check the JIRA documentation and see. Maybe you could try and use the JIRA soap from a framework like .net/java where its simpler(and you may find a complete example specific for JIRA) I think and then translate this to qt? (I haven't work with JIRA and qtsoap to tell you more), that is if you have the time(I presume your doing this to learn)

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, use [gSOAP](http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~engelen/soap.html). It's the most popular SOAP client library for C++, and has code generation.